# Salesforce Test Class for APEX Trigger

Tags: testing, triggers, salesforce, case, apex-code

I'm in need of some help regarding the writing of test script that covers enough of the below trigger that I have managed to get working on my Sandbox account.
The trigger is to create extra assets when certain types of Opportunities are closed. The Trigger seems to run fine but I really have no idea how to start writing test cases... In order for these Opportunities to close, the Account needs to have the following completed (I've included some example data - They are picklists so need to be specif amounts):

```
a.TurnoverBand__c = '<£10 million';
a.Joining_Fee__c = '£1,920';
a.Annual_Subscription__c = '£1,320';
```

Trigger as follows:

```
trigger CreateInclusiveAssetonMembershipWon on Opportunity (after insert, after update)
{
   for(Opportunity o: trigger.new)
  {
    if(o.isWon == true && o.HasOpportunityLineItem == true && ( o.Type == 'A Membership' || o.Type == 'AB Membership' || o.Type == 'A Membership Upgrade' || o.Type == 'AB Membership Upgrade' ) )
    {
     String opptyId = o.Id;
     Asset[] ast = new Asset[]{};
     Asset a = new Asset();
      {
      a = new Asset();
      a.AccountId = o.AccountId;
      a.Product2Id = '01tA0000003N1pW';
      a.Quantity = o.Inclusive_Training_Spaces_Allocated__c;
      a.Price = 300;
      a.PurchaseDate = o.CloseDate;
      a.Status = 'Purchased';
      a.Description = 'Allocated Spaces';
      a.Name = 'Membership Inclusive Training';
      ast.add(a);
      }
    insert ast;
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone could help me out on this I would be grateful!

Thanks

ETA test script for this trigger so far:

```
@isTest
 private class TrngAstOppTrigTestSuite {

      static testMethod void verifyBehaviorOnInsert_positive() {
          Account a = new Account();
      a.Name = 'New Test Account';
      a.Account_Email__c = 'testemail4trigger@test.co.uk';
          a.TurnoverBand__c = '<£10 million';
          a.Joining_Fee__c = '£1,920';
      a.Annual_Subscription__c = '£1,320';
      insert a;

          Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
          OpportunityLineItem ol = new OpportunityLineItem();
          PricebookEntry pbID = [select ID from PricebookEntry];

      o.AccountId = a.Id;
      o.Name = 'test';
          o.Type = 'A Membership';
          o.StageName = 'Needs Analysis';
          o.CloseDate = date.today();
          insert o;

      ol.OpportunityId = o.Id;
      ol.Quantity = 1;
      ol.UnitPrice = 2.00;
          ol.PricebookEntryId = pbID.Id;

          insert ol;

      o.StageName= 'Closed Won';
          update o;

          delete ol;
          delete o;
  }        
}
```

If anyone could say if I am going in the right direction with this I would be grateful. Attempting to iron out the errors but there is obviously no point if this is not going to work anyway.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a link to the Apex code documentation that shows how to create a test.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_example.htm)

All you need to do is write a testMethod that inserts or updates an Opportunity whilst meeting the criteria you define in your trigger. A good unit test should test various sceneries and verify that the code produces the expected outputs (in this case, query the new Asset).

Also, I should point out that your code has a serious flaw in it's design.
You should almost never have DML statements (or any database statements for that matter) inside of a loop. I have provided you with a fixed version of your code but I strongly suggest you head over to [developer.force.com](http://developer.force.com/) and follow some of the getting started material to avoid future headaches.

```
trigger CreateInclusiveAssetonMembershipWon on Opportunity (after insert, after update)
{
    Asset[] assets = new Asset[0];
    for(Opportunity o: trigger.new)
    {
        if(o.isWon == true && o.HasOpportunityLineItem == true && ( o.Type == 'A Membership' || o.Type == 'AB Membership' || o.Type == 'A Membership Upgrade' || o.Type == 'AB Membership Upgrade' ) )
        {

            Asset a = new Asset();
            a.AccountId = o.AccountId;
            a.Product2Id = '01tA0000003N1pW';
            a.Quantity = o.Inclusive_Training_Spaces_Allocated__c;
            a.Price = 300;
            a.PurchaseDate = o.CloseDate;
            a.Status = 'Purchased';
            a.Description = 'Allocated Spaces';
            a.Name = 'Membership Inclusive Training';
            assets.add(a);
        }
    }
    insert assets;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! I've now changed my Trigger code and will make sure not to include any DML in loops from now on... Regarding the testing I have got to the following - Could anyone say if I'm going in the right direction? I found the example on the DeveloperForce page somewhat confusing. Many thanks.

Comment: After taking a quick glance at your test example I can say that you definitely need to just go through the tutorials and guides provided by developer.force.com.

For example; your test code has no assert statements, without them you verify that your code does not have uncaught exceptions but you do not confirm that it works as expected. You also have unnecessary DML delete statements at the end the test, changes to objects in test code are never committed to the database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - your trigger has the trouble on implementation, because it isn't BULK.
Read the following articles for more details:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_bulk_idioms.htm
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/04/20/writing-bulk-triggers-for-salesforce/

The main trouble is using DML operation in the for loop.

Regarding a testing process for this code I think that the best way is using the following scheme:

you should to test all possible behavior on your code, and negative scenarios should be covered as well as positive. Thus

```apex
 @isTest
 private class OpportunityTriggerTestSuite {

      static testMethod void verifyBehaviorOnInsert_positive() {
          // prepare correct opportunity and insert it
          // perform checking for opportunity and assets states
          // use System.assertEquals() or System.assert() methods
          // http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm

      }

      static testMethod void verifyBehaviorOnUpdate_positive() {
          // prepare correct opportunity and insert it
          // change a few fields on opportunity and update it
          // perform assertion for opportunity and assets
      }

      static testMethod void verifyBehaviorOnInsert_negative() {
          // prepare incorrect opportunity and insert it
          // perform assertion for opportunity and assets expected states/error/etc.
      }

      static testMethod void verifyBehaviorOnInsert_negative() {
          // prepare correct opportunity and insert it
          // check state
          // change a few fields in such manner that opportunity will be incorrect and update it
          //  perform assertion for opportunity and assets expected states/error/etc.
      }
 }
```

Hope this might be helpful for you

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've now changed my Trigger code and will make sure not to include any DML in loops from now on... Regarding the testing I have got to the test script I have added in my original question - Could anyone say if I'm going in the right direction? I found the example on the DeveloperForce page somewhat confusing. Many thanks.